# How do I split a hash into two arrays based on key and value in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

So I am trying to split a Hash into two Arrays, one with the keys and one with the values.

So far I have:

```
hash = { Matsumoto: "Ruby", Ritchie: "C", Backus: "Fortran", McCarthy: "Lisp" }
```

Im able to make an array out of keys *or* values like so:

```
hash.map { |creator, proglang| creator }
```

But I'm unable to make two arrays, one containing the keys *and* one containing the values.  I've played around with a number of methods and I'm at a loss.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
keys, values = hash.keys, hash.values

 > keys
 # => [:Matsumoto, :Ritchie, :Backus, :McCarthy] 
 > values
 # => ["Ruby", "C", "Fortran", "Lisp"]
```

Comment: Thank you.  As I often find with Ruby, the answer is so much simpler than what I was attempting to do. ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to Hash class methods:

```
hash.keys
hash.values
```

which return arrays of keys and values respectively

See
http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Hash.html
for more details

Answer (score 0):

```
keys, values = hash.to_a.transpose
  #=> [[:Matsumoto, :Ritchie, :Backus  , :McCarthy],
  #    ["Ruby"    , "C"     , "Fortran", "Lisp"   ]]
```

also works, but `keys()` and `values()` are provided for this very task.

Comment: Yes, I was reading about the transpose method as well.  There are so many useful / interesting built-in methods in Ruby.